# printing a BST in a tree format in turbo c

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I want to print the contents of my BST in a tree format like:

my current print output:

10 -> 20 -> 30 -> 40 -> 60 -> 80 -> 90 ->

what i want it to be like:

```
        40
        /\
       /  \
     20    60
     / \    \
   10  30   80
              \
              90
```

I tried doing some gotoxy but for some reason i just cant get it to print like a tree, i think i need to do more than just gotoxy though. Also "\" is not really necessary just an added feature to not confuse any of you.

The Code are as follows:

Structure:

```
struct btnode
{
    int value;
    struct btnode *l;
    struct btnode *r;
}*root = NULL, *temp = NULL, *t2, *t1;
```

print:

```
void inorder(struct btnode *t)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        printf("No elements in a tree to display");
        return;
    }
    if (t->l != NULL)    
        inorder(t->l);
        printf("%d -> ", t->value);
    if (t->r != NULL)    
        inorder(t->r);
}
```

my attempt in tree printing:

```
void print(struct btnode *t, int x, int i, int y)
{
    i = i / 2 + 2;
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        printf("No elements in a tree to display");
        return;
    }

    if (t->l != NULL){
        print(t->l, (x + i), i, (y + 1));
    }

    if (t->r != NULL){
        print(t->r, (x + i), i, (y + 1));
    }
    gotoxy(x, y * 2);
    printf("%d -> ", t->value);
}
```

Any idea on how I can achieve the tree output base on my current output code, though I assume that i need to do some more if and else to turn it as a tree. anything would be of help, a guide or an idea would really be appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Try printing the tree horizontally first, that's easier. Pass information on the indentation level to the `print` function and, of course, print the indentation and end your printing format with a newline. Also, printing should occur between the recursive calls, not after them.

Comment: What do you expect the answer to look like if you add 35, 41, and 50 to the data set.

Comment: @MOehm, how does that help? Say you are on the "30" node, it should not print a newline, because "60" has not been processed yet.

Comment: @DwayneTowell: Yeah, right. I've now edited the comment to suggest printing the tree linearly and flipped first before attempting the rather difficult format above. I've missed the point by not noticing that the tres is drawn in curses, sorry.

Comment: @MOehm do you mind providing a solution for that one, so what i have to do first is to print the tree horizontally and pass the that value to the print function to be converted to tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky question. Let's first look at a simpler problem: How to print the tree horizontally with the root to the left and the branches growing towards the right. This can be done without cursor positioning in the console window by keeping track of the indentation level:

```
void horizontal(struct btnode *t, int level)
{
    int l = level;

    if (t == NULL) return;

    horizontal(t->l, level + 1);
    while (l--) printf("    ");
    printf("-> %d\n", t->value);
    horizontal(t->r, level + 1);
}
```

Printing the tree from top to bottom is similar. The indentation is now the position from the top. The tricky part is how to advance printing to the right. In the simple console example, that is done by printing a new line. Here, we must advance the `x` position. This can be done with a global variable `x`, but you can also keep the state in a variable pointed to in the print function:

```
void print(struct btnode *nd, int *x, int y)
{    
    if (nd == NULL) return;

    print(nd->l, x, y + 4);
    gotoxy(*x, y);
    printf("%d", nd->value);
    *x += 4;
    print(nd->r, x, y + 4);
}
```

Call the `print` function like this:

```
int x = 0;
print(root, &x, 0);
```

Comment: `nd` is what you call `t` in your code - should have used your nomenclature, sorry. The value of `nd` or `t` is `root` in the fisrt call, of course. (I don't use `root` at all in my `print` and check for `NULL` inside the function. With your logic, you'll always have to do the check on the call. This is in a way better, because you save unnecessary calls, but it's also potentially dangerous, because the client code has to do the checking.)

Comment: i see, thanks again :). is there anyway for me to check if the height of tree reach a certain value?

Comment: Sure - the current height is `y`. You could return early when it exceeds a certain value to crop your tree.

Comment: where is the definition of the function --> gotoxy(*x, y);

Comment: @YogeeshHT: I believe that `gotoxy(x, y)` is part of Turbo C's `<conio.h>` suite. The OP also uses this in the example code. The more portable `ncurses` library has `move`.

Comment: @YogeeshHT: So much the better. Turbo C is rather old.